# by-passing cakephp naming convention for tables

Tags: database, cakephp, model

It is a rule in cakephp, in creating your tables, it must be the plural form of your model. The thing is, due to some complex situations, I cannot rename a table here which is in singular form. That's the reason why cakephp is giving me an error. I tried this:

```
class Color_Schema extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'ColorSchema';
    var $useTable = 'color_schema';
}
```

but it does not work.

it still gives me this error...

```
Error: Table color_schemas for model ColorSchema was not found in datasource default.
```

Comment: The table names in your error code and your class don't match... is this a typo?

Comment: nope.. my table name is really color_schema .... its singular form.. but cake has his own naming rule that for tables, it should be the plural form of its model.. however due to complex situations, i should not rename my table for this error to be written off. please help

Comment: I should've asked this before submitting my answer but what version of Cake are you using? CakePHP < 2.0 or 2.0+?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that custom Inflector rules are the solution here. Please take a look at 
[Inflection configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#loading-custom-inflections). Something like

```
Inflector::rules('plural', array('irregular' => array('color_schema' => 'color_schema')));
```

Might work for you, although I am not a Inflector expert.

Comment: If you name your classes and refer to them correctly there should be no need to mess with the inflection rules.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the code where you are trying to access the model but by the looks of your error message you are forgetting the underscore when referring to the model. You need to do something like this:

```
$this->Color_Schema->read(null, 1);
```

Also, don't forget to add the model to the `$uses` array at the top of your controller:

```
public $uses = array('Color_Schema');
```